# Using BufferedReader or Scanner to read a txt file. in my example only the Scanner works. WHY?

Tags: java, arrays, try-catch, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

Using the BufferedReader method instead of the Scanner to read a txt file, containing all prime numbers between 2 and 10000. 
I want to put the integers in an array tall. 
With the Scanner method it works but not with the BufferedReader equivalent.

The try statement works with both methods, but when i'm closing the BufferedReader in the finally statement, it says my variables don't exist.
If i use the Scanner method, it's working.

Scanner (works):

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException {
    File file = new File ("C:/Users/Victor/workspace/Bvijfb/Priem.txt");
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    FileWriter xw = new FileWriter("Priem.txt");
    PrintWriter yw = new PrintWriter(xw);

    int i;
    boolean isPriem;
    int[] tall = new int[1240];

    for (i = 2; i < 10000; i++) {
        isPriem = true;

        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                isPriem = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isPriem == true)
            yw.println("" + i);
    }

    yw.close();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    int a = 0;

    try {
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) { 
            if(sc.hasNextInt()){
                tall[a] = sc.nextInt();
                a++;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
     } finally {
         sc.close();
          }
}
```

The try statement Using the BufferedReader method:

```
try{            
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);       
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);              
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        int a = 0;
        int value = 0;      

        while ((value = br.read()) != -1) { 
            tall[a] = value;
            a++;
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
           is.close();
           isr.close();
           br.close();
        }
```

Comment: br.read() reads a character not an integer.  It returns an `int` value so it can return `-1` to indicate the file has finished.

Comment: For the scanner you only need to check for `while (sc.hasNextInt()) {`

Answer (score 0):

Your scanner code is looking for an int by looking for *characters* that define an `int`. So for instance, the three characters `'1'`, `'2'`, and `'3'`, in a row, are read as the int value `123` by your `Scanner` code.

But your `BufferedReader` code is working at a lower level than that; it works at the *individual character* level. So when you do `br.read()` for the first time on my `123` example, you get the value 49 (`'1' == 49`).

`BufferedReader` doesn't implement the parsing functionality that `Scanner` does. If you want it, use `Scanner` (or implement your own custom if necessary).

---

Unrelated side note: On any vaguely-recent version of Java, your `try` in the `BufferedReader` example would be much better off as a try-with-resources:

```
try (
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);       
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);              
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr)
    ) {
    int a = 0;
    int value = 0;      

    while ((value = br.read()) != -1) { 
        tall[a] = value;
        a++;
    }
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace(); // This is also generally poor practice, but for quick-and-dirty code...
}
```

Note that I never call `close`. I don't have to, try-with-resources handles it for me, and handles it property regardless of where or when an exception is thrown. In your code, for instance, if for some reason `new InputStreamReader(is)` threw, you'd leave `is` open.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, when using a BufferedReader, you probably want to be using readLine() instead of read(). Read consumes a binary byte at a time; readLine() converts a line of bytes into a String and (assuming these files are one-line-per-number) that String will be the representation of a prime number.

If there is more than one number per line of text in the file, you'll need to split the String.

In order to convert that String to an int, you'll need to run Integer.parseInt() on it.

Also, you can remove some of the setup ceremony as follows:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
```

Or even just

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
```